# What are MATLAB DLLS?

Tags: python, matlab, dll

I want to call Matlab scripts in Python 2.7.10 in Windows 7. I found a package called [pymatlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymatlab) which "lets Python users interface and communicate with MATLAB from Python. Pymatlab makes it easier for users to integrate a project with a large MATLAB codebase into python scripts by using MATLAB scripts as a part of the python program."

I don't understand the preparing part:

> Win:
>
> On Windows make sure the Matlab DLLs are in your “Path” environment variable. This version is not tested in Windows but should be possible to run with some debugging efforts.

What are Matlab DLLs? What can I do to add the Matlab DLLs to my “Path” environment variable?

Comment: Googling DLL would tell you what they are.

Comment: maybe this'll help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows   the matlab dlls are components that can be loaded by a program(named something like blah.dll )...likely you'll need to browse the matlab folders to find where they are.